# Getting org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException after deploying spring security application on jboss

Tags: spring, spring-security, jboss

I am trying to deploy a Spring Boot application on `WildFly 9.0.1`.

I want authenticate the user using Spring Security using the `UserDetails` interface. But I am getting the following exception after deployment when I am trying to access secured rest services:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is
  org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
  io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
  io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
  io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
  org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
  io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
  io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
  io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
  io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
  io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
  io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
  io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
  io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
  io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
  io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
  io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
  org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
  io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
  io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
  io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
  io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
  io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
  io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
  io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
  io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
```

My technology stack is:

```
Spring boot 1.5
WildFly 9.0.1
Spring Security 4
```

What configurations need to be done to access my web application deployed on WildFly?

Basic Configuration details.

1. SecurityConfig.java

   ```
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {        
       http.httpBasic().and().cors().and().authorizeRequests()
       .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()      
       .anyRequest().authenticated().and()        
       .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(
         CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
        .logout()
        .deleteCookies("remove")
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))         
        .permitAll();

   }


         @Autowired
          public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
          throws Exception {
               auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());

          }
   ```
2. UserController.java

   ```
      @GetMapping("/user")
      @ResponseBody
      public User user() {        
       User user = getPricipalUser();      
         return user;
       }

   private User getPricipalUser() {
       User user = null;
       Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
      .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
       if (principal instanceof User) {
           user = (User) principal;
           logger.info("User Info = " + user);
       } else {
           logger.error("Principal issue");
       }
       return user;
   }
   ```

Code is deployed in Wildfly successfully but when try to access http://<<>>:8090/user getting error as authenticationCredentialsNotFoundException

Comment: Could you include a minimal configuration that reproduces the issue? You might be missing an `AuthenticationEntryPoint`, but it's hard to tell without more information.

Comment: SecurityConfig:

Comment: Thanks for posting that, Savita. It will be much easier to get the help you need if you do two additional things: 1. Put all your configuration in the question section, not some in the question section and some as an answer, as you have done. 2. Make your question clearer by placing code in well-indented code blocks and non-code (like your SecurityConfig: label) in paragraph blocks. In the first case, people wanting to help may not realize the code that you have posted in the answer section is actually part of your question. In the second case, folks may misread poorly formatted code.

Comment: Also, the configuration you have given is non the minimal configuration. I know this because you have contradictory configuration for `csrf`. On the one hand, you are configuring the token repository for csrf and on the other you are disabling it. Try and reduce your configuration to the smallest possible while still reproducing the behavior.

Comment: A couple of things I don't understand: Why are you configuring login and logout endpoints for a REST service? Why csrf with a REST service? You state in your description "when I am trying to access secure rest services". If you indeed trying to secure a restful service, maybe consider this article: http://www.baeldung.com/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security

Comment: Application is access via Angular 2, csrf is enabled for that. Able to deploy application on wildfly 10.